# AWS EC2 instance custom DNS name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

When I create a new EC2 instance, and I give it a public IPv4 address, it assigns a "Public IPv4 DNS" that looks something like "ec2-55-55-55-55.region.amazonaws.com".

Is there a way to customize the automatically assigned addresses?

For example, when new EC2 instances are launched, I want it to assign something like "ec2-55-55-55-55.region.aws.example.com".

I was thinking this would be useful for things such as `.ssh/config` where I can match based on the hostname

```
Hostname *.aws.example.com
  SSH_OPTIONS
```

I am sure I can make this work by writing a bunch of logic triggered by EC2 actions, but was hoping there was something more or less provided by AWS (Route 53 integration?) that would let you do it.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

Comment: AWS in general treats each service as kind-of siloed building blocks. Integration between services is lacking in a lot of areas of AWS, which is why they create other services to "glue" them together like elastic beanstalk

Comment: Thanks. I guess the feature I am looking for is called Dynamic DNS, or some notion of that. This article gave me some tips on how I might do it with CloudWatch and Lambda. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-dynamic-dns-for-route-53-using-cloudwatch-events-and-lambda/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of January 2021, there is no possibility to *automatically* register the public IP address of the Elastic Network Interface (ENI) of a created EC2 instance under a particular DNS name (or some form of proposed "pattern") in Route 53 as an A/AAAA record.

Just like you said, you gonna have to trigger AWS API calls to do that by any means provided (CloudWatch Events, EventBridge Events or as part of any Infrastructure-as-Code deployment of your EC2 instances using CloudFormation, CDK, Terraform, etc).

Of course, if your domain is not administered under a Route 53 Public Hosted Zone, you have to take appropriate actions on behalf of your domain registrar in order to register the public IP address under any A/AAAA record.